# How to send updates/deletes to nested records properly in a dynamic way in a GraphQL or REST system?

Tags: json, rest, graphql

I am somewhat reinventing the wheel here, but I am trying to figure out my API API for updating deeply nested records all at once.

The example is a dictionary, with this sort of schema for a "term":

```
{
  type: 'term',
  id: uuid,
  base: {
    id: termId,
  },
  singular: true,
  slug: 'create',
  plural: true,
  time: 'past, present, future',
  continuous: true,
  completed,
  aspect: 'verb',
  sense: 1,
  images: [
    
  ],
  gloss: {
    text: 'gloss'
  },
  etymology: {
    text: ''
  },
  origin: [
    {
      id: flowId,
    }
  ],
  derivations: [

  ],
  translations: [
    {
      id: termId
    }
  ],
  pronunciations: [
    {
      name: 'ipa',
      text: '',
    }
  ],
  definitions: [
    {
      text: '',
      similarities: [
        {
          id: termId,
        }
      ],
      definitions: [

      ]
    },
    {
      text: '',
      source: {
        id: citeId,
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the simplest case, we create each object in the nested tree one at a time through the REST API (given we are in the "creation" phase).

```
POST /api/term { slug: 'foo' } => id == 123
POST /api/term/123/definition { text: 'hello' }
POST /api/term/123/definition { text: 'another' }
...
```

But that seems inefficient in several ways. But it might be fine if our UI form saves after editing each input. Might be kind of tricky to implement.

But a simpler approach would be to send the full JSON payload at once:

```
POST /api/term
{
  slug: 'foo',
  definitions: [
    { text: 'hello' },
    { text: 'another' },
  ]
}
```

That would work pretty fine in this "creation" case (as opposed to update/delete), I would just on the backend break it down into individual commands like we did before, but at the DB level basically.

But the question is how to do this more "batch" approach, with update and delete? It seems you can't really in a straightforward way do that, is that a correct reading of the situation?

Say you had that term already created:

```
{
  slug: 'foo',
  definitions: [
    { text: 'hello' },
    { text: 'another' },
  ]
}
```

Now you want to add a definition, you would have to either:

```
POST /api/term/:id/definition { text: 'a third' }
```

Or do:

```
POST /api/term
{
  definitions: [
    { id: 1 },
    { id: 2 },
    { text: 'a third' },
  ]
}
```

But then that starts to get hairy, what do we mean by `{ id: 1 }` and such? I was thinking "keep the records we just pass in by ID, and create records that don't have an ID". But what if you go tmore complex, and say definitions had a "similarities" array of related terms.

```
POST /api/term
{
  definitions: [
    { id: 1, similarities: [ { id: 125 } ] },
    { id: 2 },
    { text: 'a third' },
  ]
}
```

Now we edit the first record, and create the last.

Now say we want to delete the second. In the UI form, we delete second, add similarities to the first, and create the third.

```
POST /api/term
{
  definitions: [
    { id: 1, similarities: [ { id: 125 } ] },
    { id: 2, _delete: true },
    { text: 'a third' },
  ]
}
```

Something like that? (Borrowing from old Rails what I remember).

#### Summary/Question

Basically to summarize, you might have a deeply nested record in which you create some parts of it (nested records), update parts of it, and delete parts of it all at once.

What is the standard way of handling this situation from a REST API or GraphQL API standpoint (basically any way of sending JSON over to the server)? What is the recommended way of being able to "batch" send-over these creates/updates/deletes all at once for a nested JSON object, and have it write efficiently out to PostgreSQL tables? I don't need to know about the PostgreSQL details, just saying that to know where my head's at.

It's been a while since I sat down and worked on a JSON API, so have been out of the loop for a while now and don't have in my memory the best ways of handling this sort of situations.

### Other Notes

If the "dictionary term" was a large record, say with 15 definitions and long etymology and such, then sending the whole term every time you change a piece would be inefficient. So that brings me back to the first solution of having API routes for each record type, and calling them one-by-one. So I am sort of stuck and confused.

Now thinking of something like this:

```
{
  type: 'term',
  action: 'revision',
  properties: {
    definitions: [
      {
        action: 'revision',
        filter: {
          id: 123,
        },
        properties: {
          text: {
            action: 'overwrite',
            value: 'bar',
          }
        }
      },
      {
        action: 'deletion',
        filter: {
          id: 125
        }
      },
      {
        action: 'addition',
        properties: {
          text: 'foo'
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you had a look at the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) specification? It proposes a solution to modeling each nesting level as a separate resource while still allowing them to be fetched in a single request by [including related resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes). The [Atomic Operations extension](https://jsonapi.org/ext/atomic/) provides a way to create, update and delete multiple resources at the same time. It offers [sparse fieldsets](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets) as a solution to avoid overfetching.

Comment: coming out in 2000, i consider rest a replacement for remote procedure calls and object request brokers that imho worked in 80s and 90s but failed with more and more clients. and in both rpc and orbs you do tiny little calls. obj->setFirstName('Santa'). obj->setLastName('Paws'); each function is sent over the wire. rest in practice is usually not as micro but rest was not designed for a batch job. further efficiency was also not a factor. i'm an advocate of json:api but their related resource recommendation is a bit hefty. where is this data going?!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this, but better answers are welcome!

### Query

```
{
  action: {
    type: {
      slug: 'insert',
    },
  },
  filter: {
    type: 'flow',
  },
  select: {
    language: {
      id: true,
      slug: true,
      title: {
        id: true,
        transcription: {
          select: {
            script: {
              id: true,
            },
            gram: {
              id: true,
              text: true,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    transcription: {
      size: true,
      select: {
        script: {
          id: true,
        },
        gram: {
          id: true,
          text: true,
        },
      },
    },
    pronunciation: {
      size: true,
      select: {
        gram: {
          id: true,
          text: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  effect: {
    language: {
      effect: {
        id: {
          effect: language.id,
        },
      },
    },
    transcription: [
      {
        action: {
          type: {
            slug: 'insert',
          },
        },
        effect: {
          script: {
            effect: {
              id: { effect: script.id },
            },
          },
          gram: {
            effect: {
              text: { effect: 'foo' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    pronunciation: [
      {
        action: {
          type: {
            slug: 'insert',
          },
        },
        effect: {
          gram: {
            effect: {
              text: { effect: 'bar' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        action: {
          type: {
            slug: 'insert',
          },
        },
        effect: {
          gram: {
            effect: {
              text: { effect: 'bae' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

### Response

```
{
  language: {
    id: 'stub',
    slug: 'ghotuo',
    title: {
      id: 'stub',
      transcription: {
        list: [
          {
            script: { id: 'stub' },
            gram: { id: 'stub', text: 'Ghotuo' },
            id: 'stub',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  id: 'stub',
  transcription: {
    list: [
      {
        script: { id: 'stub' },
        gram: { id: 'stub', text: 'foo' },
        id: 'stub',
      },
    ],
    size: 1,
  },
  pronunciation: {
    list: [
      { gram: { id: 'stub', text: 'bar' }, id: 'stub' },
      { gram: { id: 'stub', text: 'bae' }, id: 'stub' },
    ],
    size: 2,
  },
}
```

### Summary

It's kind of like GraphQL in many ways, you can fetch lists and the count for a list this way, project the fields you want using `select`, and filter on every level of the select query. Then the `effect` is used to specify what properties you are writing to. For insert queries, only nested inserts are allowed. But for update queries, you can have insert/update/remove scattered about.