# Techniques for preventing recursive access to records through GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I am working on a sort of [GraphQL-like JSON API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76088260/169992) system, and now am wondering how I can prevent "hackers" from exploding a query by recursively expanding nodes, like this:

```
users {
  username
  posts {
    title
    comments {
      user {
        posts {
          title
          comments {
            user {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone figured out a general way of solving this problem? The only solution I have heard of or seen is limiting the *depth* of the query to like 7-10 nodes. The other solution I can think of is to explore each and every possible query and define an interface that delineates what can and can't be queried in that specific nested tree, sort of like this:

```
{
  users: {
    username: true,
    posts: {
      title: true,
      comments: {
        message: true,
        user: {
          username: true,
          posts: FALSE
          comments: FALSE
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But that would be brittle and you'd have to potentially keep tinkering with it to let new unforeseen queries through....

Is there a way to do this automatically somehow, some sort of pattern? I haven't been able to see a pattern to the madness yet. If no one has figured out an ideal system yet, what do people typically do to prevent this problem in production?

Comment: Don't know if it is still current, but according to [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/91), recursion in GraphQL is explicitly not "allowing" recursion because it has no way of finding out before processing if things would do so unbounded. Someone is also just suggesting a "depth" limit to mitigate.

Comment: Limiting query depth is the standard approach but as @Christian.K points out recursion is not supported anyway.